# EMenuService throwing nullpointerException in @postConstruct

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am trying to customize right mouse click in my RCP E4 browser, I created the popup menu in application.e4xmi, and here is my code for triggering the right click event.

for creating the part inside a part stack:

```
 public void showBrowser(Composite parent, EModelService service,
            MApplication application, EPartService partservice) {
        MPartStack mpartstack = (MPartStack) service.find(
                "com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.partstack.confps", application);
        MPart navigationpart = partservice
                .createPart("com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.partdescriptor.navigate_pd");
        navigationpart.setLabel("Visual Navigator");
        // for adding the menucontext

        //
        mpartstack.getChildren().add(navigationpart);
        MPartStack metadata_ps = (MPartStack) service.find(
                "com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.partstack.metadataPS", application);
        metadata_ps.setVisible(true);
        MPart metadatapart = partservice
                .createPart("com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.partdescriptor.metadatadesc");
        metadatapart.setLabel("Metadata");
        metadata_ps.getChildren().add(metadatapart);
    }
```

Inside the part descriptor: " com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.partdescriptor.navigate_pd "

```
@Inject
    IEclipseContext context;
    EMenuService menuservice;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createControll(Composite parent, EModelService service,
            MApplication application) {
   // some other stuffs
   menuservice.registerContextMenu(browser, "com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.popupmenu");
}
```

its showing NullPointerException at runtime, i tried to inject EMenuService in postconstruct method also, but in that case as expected the result is worse (you know why). I am pretty new in RCP E4, so advanced sorry if I am making any basic mistake.

Comment: What is this class exactly? Where is it declared in the application.e4xmi?

Comment: Its a partDescriptor, being called after a certain number of parts are executed, with some user defined values with it, to open a browser and some other detailed information along with it.

Comment: How and where is it created? It sounds like you are using a context which does not a menu service (for example a dialog context).

Comment: I am dynamically creating a part which is implementing this partDescriptor (where the code is ). I did not add any bindingContext manually.(If i understood your question)

Comment: Show us the code where you create this part.

Comment: Please insert IEclipseContext as parameter in your showBrowser and print it out so we can see if its an Part Eclipse Context or something else.

Comment: @greg-449 I edited my question with where i am createing this part.

Comment: @MatthiasH IEclipseContext is returning me 
'PartImpl (com.example.e4.rcp.wizard.part.config) Context'

and IEclipseContext.get(EMenuService.class) is returning me null

Comment: According to the Vogella EclipseRCP Tutorial you need dependancy to org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt and org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench. Check please if you have them. Do you use Luna (4.4) ? Because there was a little Change for EMenuService. It moved in a other Plugin

Comment: Actually what i understood is, in this case there is no EMenuService object added by default in the eclipsecontext. So is there any way to manually initiate it emenuservice/ menuservice object in the eclipsecontext or maybe in that part itself instead of using DI?

Answer (score 0):

You must use @Inject on each field that you want injected:

```
@Inject
IEclipseContext context;
@Inject
EMenuService menuservice;
```

Your existing code is only asking for `IEclipseContext` to be injected.

Comment: Thanks greg, but then also i am getting an error which i was getting when i tried:

@PostConstruct
 public void createControll(Composite parent, EModelService service,
   MApplication application,EMenuService menuservice) {}

the exception is: Unable to process "VisualNavigation.menuservice": no actual value was found for the argument "EMenuService"

So i think there is a problem injecting this EMenuService value in the class .